# password field background changes after using iscroll4

Tags: cordova, iscroll4

I have implemented iscroll in login page, actually my password field has brown background color, when focus on password field to type text the background vanished and came white background. Could any one suggest the solution for this issue.

```css
   input[type="text"],input[type="password"], input[type="email"]
    {
      height: 40px;
      width: 200px;   
      -moz-border-radius:5px; 
      -webkit-border-radius:5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #wrapper
    {
      position:absolute; 
      z-index:1; top:13%;
      bottom:10%; left:0;
      width:100%; 
      overflow:auto;
    }

    #scroller
    {
      position:absolute; 
      z-index:1; 
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); 
      width:100%; padding:0%;
    }
```

```html
 <form name="login" id="login_form">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="login_container">
          <div id="email_input">
            <input type='text' id='email' class='not_capital' placeholder='Email' autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off"/>
          </div>

          <div id="password_input">
            <input type='password' id='password' placeholder='Password' />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" class="small_button" value="Login" id="login" />
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define a seperate style for the focus of password field

```
input[type="password"]:focus
    {
     background-color:#333;
...... other properties -------
    }
```

Comment: Yes i already created the separate style here is the code..
input[type="password"]:focus
{
border-color: #A9E2F3;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #A9E2F3;
 
}

Comment: try setting !important; after background-color

Comment: tried with !important; its not working,the thing is its happening only in android 2.3.4 mobile.